# Download file from a webpage when the downloading starts after 10 seconds

Tags: c#, webclient

I have used WebClient to download files from Direct URLs like, http://www.xyz.com/somefile.zip or http://www.xyz.com/somefile.pdf.

But there are pages, where they say "Your download should start automatically. If not click here" . How do I Programatically download the file ?

Comment: By hiring a developer, probably.

Comment: Every site can be different.  Good luck with that

Comment: Assuming you can already call `WebClient` to programatically click the button, you just have to find out how long to wait before that button becomes available.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3):

There should be a work-through, check the source file and see if it is ajax or just some plain javascript that makes the link available after a few seconds. In the later case (which is more common) just fire the link. If its asynchronous see if the link contains some unique identifier or there is a pattern. If you could find the pattern, bingo! otherwise...well not much that you could there...

Answer (score 0):

Typically, sites doing this sort of thing inject a hidden IFRAME into their markup containing a URL that points directly at the target file. Your browser then downloads the file in that frame, triggering the download notice without navigating the top-level frame.

You can use a tool like Fiddler to watch this behavior and see the "true" URL from which the file download is generated.

As @climbage notes, however, each site works differently and you will not be able to generalize what happens on any given site such that your code works against all other sites.